# How to add a sticky searchbar to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

i tried to add a sticky searchbar to my UItableViewController which is embedded inside a tabBarController. But i dont get it. I tried something out with a containerView, but i thought this couldnt be the right way to do this. Is there any best practice to add a sticky searchbar on top of a tableView ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use searchdisplaycontroller. It is really easy to integrate with a tableview and creates all the animations while searching.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hmm, the searchDisplayController looks very nice but if i initialize it with the searchbar i added to tableviewcontroller it is still not sticky. If i scroll my tableview, the searchbar scrolls with it. Which i think is normal because i added the bar to my tableview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use UITableViewController.  You have to use a normal UIViewController and add the search bar and table view as separate subviews.  Otherwise the searchbar will scroll with the table, as you've discovered.